# Datatable export to excel and formatting number

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

can you help me understand how to format the numbers (amounts) when I export data to excel?
If on the datatable I display them correctly, on excel they are displayed but (incorrect formatting.
example:
15.405 --> 1540.5 instead of 15.405
1.663.405 --> 1663.405 instead of 1.663.405

I post the portion of datatable code where I attempt to format the amounts correctly

```js
buttons:     [
                    {
            extend: 'excelHtml5',
                        footer: true,
                        className: "buttons-excel buttons-html5",
                        text: "<img src='img/excel.png'/>",
                        title:  'My_report',
            exportOptions: {
                          format: {
                            body: function(data, row, column, node) {
                              var y = data.replace('.', '');
                              return y.replace(',', '.');
                            },
                            footer: function(data, row, column, node) {
                              var y = data.replace('.', '');
                              return y.replace(',', '.');
                            }
                          }
                        }
                }
                ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are replacing , to . so that only you are getting result like that

try like this

```
buttons: [ {
            extend: 'excelHtml5'
        } ]
```